# TS7006 parameter is not identified as typed

Tags: typescript

I am building a web based project. It has both React tsx files and plain typescript files in it. The project is getting compiled with webpack using ts-loader.

I have a file called Host.ts the contents are:

```
import {IService} from "../Services/IService"

export interface IHost 
{
    GetService(serviceName: string): IService
}

class Host
{
    GetService(serviceName: string): IService {
        console.log(serviceName);
        return {} as IService
    }
}

export function getHost() : IHost
{
    let host = new Host();
   
    return host;
}
```

When I import this file into a React Component's tsx file I get this error from webpack

```
ERROR in C:\Users\mikedice\source\repos\mikedice_hackathon_9_2023\src\Host\Host.ts
./src/Host/Host.ts 2:15-26
[tsl] ERROR in {obfuscated root path}\src\Host\Host.ts(2,16)
      TS7006: Parameter 'serviceName' implicitly has an 'any' type.
ts-loader-default_5c60789ee8ba319c
 @ ./src/Editors/DDUE/DDUEDocument.tsx 4:0-42 6:17-24

webpack 5.85.0 compiled with 1 error in 11806 ms
```

And the tsconfig used by webpack is:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./dist/",
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "module": "es6",
      "target": "es6",
      "jsx": "react",
      "allowJs": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    }
  }
```

I already know I can set noImplicitAny to false and that does clear the error. But want all of my project to be typed (hence the use of TypeScript) so I don't think turning that off is a solution to this problem.

I can't see anywhere in the code where serviceName is *not* typed as a string. So, I have no idea why I see this error and I'm pretty stuck on this. Any ideas?